# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource' using react-native and selenium

Tags: android, react-native, selenium, gradle, selendroid

I am trying to use selenium/selendroid with a react native app and while adding the needed libraries the follow error comes at build time. What is causing this?

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
> 2 files found with path 'README.md' from inputs:
> -
>
> - /Users/nalinsinha/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2c4ea8cf37778c1efba9d9531427ae43/jetified-selendroid-client-0.17.0.jar
> - /Users/nalinsinha/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/c421fc41e3640b807cd5c8572df45ca5/jetified-selendroid-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies.jar
>
>   Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
>   https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
>   for more information